# Update another model's object after a form submit

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am attempting to update another model's object after a form submit. I would like the single object, already in existence within the `Savings` model, updated to reflect the most recent `Entry` submission.

**Process:**

Once the `Entry` form is filled out and submitted, I need the `Savings` object, which contains the "total" fields, to be updated.

The `Savings` fields take data from the `Entry` form, sums it, and posts it to its corresponding fields. For example, `Savings.total_spent_euros` sums `Entry.euros_sums`, and `Savings.total_spent_dollars` sums `Entry.dollars_sum`. That logic is not the issue. The problem I have is I currently have to open the `Savings` object in `admin` and save it every time I want the object to include the most recent entries. I would like to automate that.

**models.py**

```
    class Entry(models.Model):
        date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,)
        euros = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
        comments = models.CharField(max_length=900, blank=True, null=True)
        euros_sum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
        xrate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
        dollars_sum = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
        daily_savings_dollars = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
        daily_savings_display = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('argent:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Savings(models.Model):
        total_spent_euros = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
        total_spent_dollars = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
        total_savings = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
        total_savings_display = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

Am I assuming correctly that my command must be entered within these two views? (I could be wrong):

**views.py**

```
class EntryCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = EntryForm
    template_name = 'argent/entry_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        Savings.objects.update(id=1)
        return super(EntryCreate, self).form_valid(form)


class EntryUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Entry
    form_class = EntryForm
    template_name = 'argent/entry_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        Savings.objects.update(id=1)
        return super(EntryUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

However, whenever I use `Savings.objects.update(id=1)` or `Savings.objects.filter(id=1).update()`, nothing happens. What am I overlooking here?

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: Added a bit more detail.

Comment: With what data do you want to update the `Savings` obj?

Comment: All of the savings fields within Savings must be updated. Different fields within `Entry` are used to update each `Savings` field. Here is one of the fields for example: forms.py  `def clean_total_spent_dollars(self):
        sum_dollars = Entry.objects.aggregate(s=Sum('dollars_sum')).get('s')
        sum_formats = "{0:.2f}".format(sum_dollars)

        return sum_formats` So the fields within `Entry` are analyzed in order to show the "totals" within `Savings`. The example I used uses `dollars_sum` from `Entry`.

Comment: You want each time to update which `Savings` object? One with a particular `id`? These two are not related somehow.

Comment: I need to update Savings.object id=1.

Comment: OK. Try this: `Savings.objects.filter(id=1).update(**form.cleaned_data)`. But before running this you must make sure that `form.cleaned_data` has **keys (its a dictionary) exactly as** `Savings`'s model fields. Before you run this, make a `print(form.cleaned_data)` inside `form_valid`.

Comment: Although a good solution to copy data, it does not refresh the object in the db with what I want. I do not want to copy data from one field to the other, I need the object in `Savings` to refresh itself so that it runs all of its own logic after I submit a form. How would I get the object in `Savings` with `id=1` to refresh itself? Please let me know if that does not make sense, and sorry for not being more clear.

Comment: Have you tried `s = Savings.objects.get(id=1)` and then `s.refresh_from_db()` ? More on [`refresh_from_db`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db)

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, `refresh_from_db()` has no effect on my `object` within the `Savings` model. If I use `s.refresh_from_db('total_savings')` ("total_savings" being a field within my Savings model), I get an error stating `The connection total_savings doesn't exist`. I read through the documentation and still can't get my `object` in my `Savings` model to refresh itself with current numbers after I submit a new form.

Comment: You don't have to pass any arguments to `refresh_from_db()`. Just do `s.refresh_from_db()` and then `print(s.total_savings)`. In your syntax, in your comment above, you passed the `using` parameter (which is a database name) as `total_savings` which of course you got that error (`The connection total_savings doesn't exist`).

Comment: Ah ok. I've tried running it both ways and still don't get updated values in my Savings object. Here is what it looks like: `s = Savings.objects.get(id=1)
s.refresh_from_db()
print(s.total_savings)` I get the same value for `total_savings` that I had before running `refresh_from_db`, even though the number should have gone up. I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: From reading more about refresh_from_db, it doesn't seem like this does anything more than refresh what is already in the database. If I need my object to literally open and save itself, thus running the logic located within its form field, it looks like I may need a different solution.

Comment: If I have understand correctly, why don't you update the `Savings` obj with `id = 1` inside each `clean_***` method?

Comment: I completely misunderstood the functionality of `refresh_from_db` and `update`. You were right with your initial response regarding the `.update`. The only thing I had to add was the logic within the `view` to enable the update to include math. It didn't occur to me to do that until now. I added my updated `.views` to the original post. Thank you for continuing to help throughout all of this! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad I could help! You should either post your solution as an answer and accepted or let me post an answer and be accepted by your side!

Comment: I just posted the solution as an answer to my post. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION

With the help of nik-m we finally came up with a solution. Here is my updated `views.py`. Not only did I have to use the `.update` solution, but I had to include all of the logic that is otherwise housed within my `forms.py`.

**views.py**

```
class EntryCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = EntryForm
    template_name = 'argent/entry_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.save(self):
            # total_euros_spent
            sum_euros = Entry.objects.aggregate(s=Sum('euros_sum')).get('s')
            sum_euros_f = "{0:.2f}".format(sum_euros)

            # total_dollars_spent
            sum_dollars = Entry.objects.aggregate(s=Sum('dollars_sum')).get('s')
            sum_dollars_f = "{0:.2f}".format(sum_dollars)

            # total_sum
            sum_savings = Entry.objects.aggregate(s=Sum('daily_savings_dollars')).get('s')
            sum_format = "{0:.2f}".format(sum_savings)

            # total_sum_format
            sum_abs_savings = Entry.objects.aggregate(s=Sum('daily_savings_dollars')).get('s')
            absolute = abs(sum_abs_savings)
            sum_abs = "{0:.2f}".format(absolute)

            Savings.objects.filter(id=1).update(total_savings=sum_format, total_savings_display=sum_abs,
                                                total_dollars_spent=sum_dollars_f, total_euros_spent=sum_euros_f)

            return super(EntryCreate, self).form_valid(form)

        else:
            return self
```